# How to look at the statistical significance/insignificance in regression tables without asterisks or p-values?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value, interpretation, reporting

I am reading some papers where regression tables are shown, but I could not find where statistical significance is reported for the coefficients. The authors only discussed the significance in the text so I have no idea if I am interpreting some unmentioned variables right. Am I missing anything here?

I image of the regression table is below:

[image: regression table]

Comment: Welcome. Some papers don’t report any asterisks, but it doesn’t mean we can’t make statements about significance. Do you know how to arrive at a test statistic using the information you see?

Answer (score 5):

Statistical significance requires that the hypotheses are prespecified. There's no way on Earth the authors prespecified each coefficient in that huge table as a hypothesis. If they did, they ought to adjust for multiple comparisons, effectively throwing the results in the trash.

You can calculate the significance test with the coefficient and standard error yourself (the SE is the parenthesized value underneath). A coefficient divided by its SE should have absolute value 1.96 or higher to be statistically significant at the two sided 0.05 level. This only tells you if a coefficient is different from 0. So is that the question they're trying to answer? Maybe not.

Whether all the coefficients of a multivariate model should be reported in a table or not is a subject of debate among statisticians. These authors took the former approach it seems: report 'em all. If you can't find the table values to back it up, it may be some covariate values are suppressed, which isn't a big deal except if the authors are commenting on significance for no good reason. That should have been caught and cut out by the statistical reviewer, but what quality can you expect from peer review when reviewers work for free?

In all the papers I published, I omitted covariates that weren't part of the central problem. I include in a footnote what variables are adjusted for, and that's it. Reviewers and co-authors can really be led on a wild goose chase when they start scrutinizing results outside the scientific question. Consider age. "Age was statistically significant..." - yes and who cares? or "Age was NOT statistically significant? But it's well known..." - I don't know, maybe the other adjustments are mediators for the age effect, maybe it's a false negative, maybe the sampling frame is different from previous studies, no matter how you cut it, age is not the central question!